# Compare 2, sometimes 3 (or blank) values for distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a function to compare 2-3 values and return a yes/ no (bit) to base an insert statement off of. My problem is that occasionally the 3rd value returns as a "blank" not a null. I am not sure how to account for this in the below statement

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @var3 VARCHAR(255)

SET @var1 ='test'
SET @var2 = 'test'
SET @var3 = ''

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3

SELECT CAST(CASE
     WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) = 1 THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END AS BIT)
FROM   (VALUES (@var1),
           (@var2),
           (@var3)) t (C)
```

So for the above example, I would expect a "1" to be returned, as @var3 is blank, however that is not the case.

How do I tweak my code to account for this?

Comment: `replace(c,'',null)` though i'm unsure what you are really trying to do...

Comment: if you're creating a function, just set the default of all three parameters to NULL. when @var3 = NULL - your query is returnung 1 as you expect

Comment: `''` is still a valid, separate, string value.  If you want to treat them as `NULL`, use `NullIf(YourField, '')`

Comment: The empty string is not `NULL`.  I would expect the `count(distinct)` to return 2, not 1 (`'test'` and `''` are the two distinct values).  You need to adjust your expectations based on what the database really does.

Comment: `WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(C, ''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply exclude the empty values from your comparision:

```
WHERE t.C != ''
```

In full:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @var3 VARCHAR(255)

SET @var1 ='test'
SET @var2 = 'test'
SET @var3 = ''

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3

SELECT CAST(CASE
     WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) = 1 THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END AS BIT)
FROM   (VALUES (@var1),
           (@var2),
           (@var3)) t (C)  
WHERE t.C != ''
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of doing it this way. Your way is easier to maintain for others. Thank you

Comment: should that not be WHERE ISNULL(t.C, '') <> ''

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) to convert empty strings to `NULL`.
BTW, a short while ago I've learned about the [`SIGN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql) built in function in sql. That can shorten your query:

```
SELECT SIGN(COUNT(DISTINCT C))
FROM (VALUES 
    (NULLIF(@Var1, '')),
    (NULLIF(@Var2, '')),
    (NULLIF(@Var3, ''))) t(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this: and it solved it

```
if (len(@var2) = 0)
set @var2 = NULL
if (len(@var3) = 0)
set @var3 = null
```

The final code looks like this:

```
 DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @var3 VARCHAR(255)

 SET @var1 ='test'
 SET @var2 = ''
  SET @var3 = 'test'

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3

if (len(@var2) = 0)
set @var2 = NULL
if (len(@var3) = 0)
set @var3 = null

SELECT CAST(CASE
     WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) = 1 THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END AS BIT)
FROM   (VALUES (@var1),
           (@var2),
           (@var3)) t (C)
```

Comment: You could also replace those variable null assignments with `set @var2 = nullif(@var2, '')`